# Set table row height of row containing the cursor

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to set the table row height for the Word table row that contains the cursor in one of the cells in the row.

No text is selected; I click on a cell.

Here is my C# code that loops over all rows in the selection and adjusts the row height.

```
foreach (Row current in sel.Rows) {
  current.Height = InchesToPoints(height);
}
```

The problem is that the code works if the selection contains multiple rows (click in a cell and drag down to a second row), but the code skips the loop  if the cursor is placed in a single cell by clicking within the cell. I checked the value of `sel.Rows.Count` and it is 1 for the single row case, so I expect the loop to run once. But it skips the loop as if `sel.Rows.Count` was zero.

The selection.Type is selectionIP (in paragraph), and the selection is in a table.

Why would the loop work for two or more rows, but skip the loop when `sel.Rows.Count==1`? It's like the sel.row.count of 1 is not being treated as a row.

Maybe I need to programmatically select the entire row?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are looking for an answer in C# or VBA but it works if I loop over `sel.Cells` and change the height using `current.Row.Height`. Either that or use index-based loop `For i = 1 to sel.Rows.Count` and `sel.Rows(i).Height`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see that you and the answer below both use different ways than me and set the row height by looping over cells or using the selection end of row range number. I will try them out.

Answer (score 0):

> The selection.Type is selectionIP (in paragraph), and of course the
> selection is in a table.

This is entirely to be expected. Your selection does not contain any rows as the insertion point has been placed inside a cell. As a result the selection does not contain any table elements.

They can, however, be obtained.

If `Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` returns true `Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)` will provide the row number.

You can then set the row height using:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Rows(Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)).Height = InchesToPoints(height)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see that you and the comment above both use different ways than me and set the row height by looping over cells or using the selection end of row range number. I will try them out. I agree with you that the selection appears to contain no rows, but then why is sel.Rows.Count = 1? I will try out these solutions at my next opportunity.